# SQL max value from different tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have several tables having a field "version". I want to select the MAX value of the version from all tables at once. 
So, if t1.version = 1, t2.version=6, t3.version = 4, the return value should be "6".

I tried this, but it looks like wrong approach:

```
 SELECT MAX(t1.version, t2.version, t3.version) as maxv FROM t1, t2, t3;
```

any way to do this in a single query?
Regards.

Comment: Do you join the tables or you run the query as above? What are the primary keys for the tables?

Comment: each table has an "id" as auto increment. I tried as above, but of course it is wrong and fails.. i wrote it, just to explain what I expect to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select max(version)
from
(
  select version from t1
  union
  select version from t2
  union
  select version from t3
) T
```

Comment: - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(version)
from
(
  select Max(version) as version from t1
  union
  select Max(version) as version from t2
  union
  select Max(version) as version from t3
) a
```

Comment: the output is: Every derived table must have its own alias